# Running Eclipse php project from a shared folder

Tags: php, eclipse, project, lan, eclipse-pdt

I have been using Eclipse Kepler along with PDT tools on local system to manage PHP projects and its turned out to be a better choice for me then the other editors around.  Only problem I've found in this environment is that content assist is only available when you open a file residing in the workspace.

Now my problem,  I am assigned to work on a PHP Project which is on another system on the local LAN network.  Is there any way I can add that project folder to eclipse?  so that I can directly edit and save the files on the remote system?

Things I can't look into for various reasons

- Using a version control system
- Copy source files to local system work
  on them and then upload it (kinda have to add the remote files to the
  local eclipse project).
- Do any modifications on the target system for my convinence eg. Adding an FTP server.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get what I want by creating what you call a **Symbolic Link** in c:\wamp\www (using WAMP) folder which is also my eclipse workspace, for the network shared project I wanted to import into Eclipse.  To do this open an elevated command prompt and run this command

```
mklink /d projectname \\network_shared_folder
```

`/d` option creates a directory symbolic link.  Now, the network project will be available as a local project on the web root which can be easily imported into Eclipse (or any other IDE)

Hope this comes in handy for someone who stumbles upon this problem. Now I can get content assist for any file in the project.

Thanks.

Comment: I needed to start command prompt with right click->Run as administrator to make a link

Answer (score 0):

In the project explorer if not exist create a new project then:

1)  right-click the project and select `New > Folder`

2) Specify a name for the folder

3) click on `Advanced`

4) Check `Link to alternate location (Linked Folder)`

5) Enter a file system path, or click `Browse` to select a folder in the file system.

6) Click `Finish`

Check here for more [Creating Linked Resources on Eclipse](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/tasks-45.htm)

Comment: I forgot to mention I am on a windows machine and accessing network location with this isn't working like `\\target-pc\share-name`.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of searching, I share the solution finally found: symbolic links are not usable if the project is managed via git. 
Another solution is to use the fileSync plug-in (http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/filesync) to automatically copy folders from the source project to user projects.

Comment: If you can use GIT you are better off cloning your own copy of the project at some other location (eg. desktop).  Also, the latest versions of GIT has symbolic link support.  Do check that out.